# "Piss" in a context

Tags: word-usage

I'm now cracking up watching at [**this new comedy.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvU5dmu4sl8) "**This video seems available in only limited countries**".

From 2:20, he says,

> But what if you could piss where you like. And the experience of the others. Piss on the carpet, piss on the stairs, to take it out and just to piss.

Would you think this insane guy is using the verb piss literally (urinate, pee), or other meaning like, shit or mess?

I have a little bit of hardship understanding him.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, it means to urinate. Especially as a man, since he says *'to take it out and just to piss'*.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the verb **piss** means to pee in this context.

Let's take this part of the video:
"If you could piss where you like".

Do you notice that "mess" can't fit that phrase? This happens because we do not say "mess where". When we use the verb mess, we say **what** we will mess up, not where.

About shit, it cannot replace piss in no way.

Another thing you can notice is that this man is bringing a very indifferent situation in society, since you have never or almost never seen a human being urinating wherever he wants. We can mess up many things, but piss wherever we want? No.

To finish, rarely piss will mean mess up. By the way, I never heard someone speaking with this meaning.

Comment: I asked this question since I didn't know if  he is so insane. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. It's normal to have some doubts about this, mainly because it is usually a pejorative term.

Comment: And I'm sorry my confusion probably comes from another lines such as he is the first architect to have built an above ground basement and other says "Whatever he builds, it sucks.". Thanks anyway:).